# Throwing exception instead of returning value

Tags: java

I came across a code I needed to return a `boolean` for checking the term of case, i'll show an example:

let's say I have a `CarChecker` class that has `public boolean checkCompability(Car car)` but I want to return the reason the reason the car wasn't compatible.

First solution introduced was creating

```
public class CompabilityResult {
    private boolean isCompatible;
    private String reason;
}
```

And then reformat the function to:

```
public CompabilityResult checkCompabilty(Car car)
```

Second solution was reformat the function to :

```
public void checkCompability(Car car) throws IncompatibleException
```

And in case of incompatible car we would use the exception message.

I know there isn't a "better" solution here, since both achiveing the same result.

I really wanted to know what would be the best use cases and best practices when throwing exceptions from my own code, since functions like the one above seems more straight-forward to me when they are returning a value.

Thanks!

Comment: Exceptions should only be thrown, if the method can't keep on going because of any state. In your case you should really stick to the first solution

Comment: Yep first solution is good